# Как инициализировать массив указателей на структуру в статическом поле класса?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы, указатели

Доброго времени суток! Есть структура `Tag` и класс `Note`, содержащий, кроме прочего, массив указателей на структуру:

```
struct Tag {
    const char *tagName;
    Tag *nextTag;
};

class Note {
private:
...
    static Tag **TagCloud;
...
};
```

Как нужно инициализировать `**TagCloud` (выделить память под 1 элемент, записать в его поля структуры что-нибудь? У меня получилось инициализировать (в .cpp файле класса) только следующим образом:

```
Tag Note::**TagCloud = 0;
```

На попытки выделить память:

```
Tag Note::**TagCloud = new Tag*[1];
```

компилятор ругался ошибкой конвертирования `'Tag**' to 'Tag Note::**'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Tag ** Note::TagCloud = new Tag*[1];
```

Comment: Да, так работает. Спасибо!